# How to match Two columns with case sensitive in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, exact-match

Hi I have 2 columns A and B , in column C I need to display true if value in column A exists in Column B with exact case sensitive else false. How can I achieve this? I use vlookup and match functions but those are not matching columns with case sensitive. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I googled *excel match case sensitive formula* and found [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/exact-match-lookup-with-index-and-match) in less than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EXACT MATCH Formula

> Searches for an exact (case-sensitive) match of the value of a cell of
>   column **A**, in a range in column **B** and returns `TRUE` if found,
>   `FALSE` if not found or `""` if cell value is "".

The following is an array formula and has to be entered by
holding **LEFT CTRL SHIFT** and pressing **ENTER**:

> ```
> =IF(A1="","",NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A1,B$1:B$10),0))))
> ```

Afterwards in the formula bar it will look like this (braces **{...}**):

```
{=IF(A1="","",NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A1,B$1:B$10),0))))}
```

Answer (score 0):

The EXACT function is used to find case sensitive comparisons.

```
=ISNUMBER(AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW(A:A)/EXACT(A1, B$1:B$999), 1))
```